# Send data from javascript to view and return modified data

Tags: javascript, django, django-views

Now I'm just testing how it works so I use a trivial example. I have a variable called `text` in js. I want to send it to view, do some manipulations with it and return it to js. I managed to send `text` via ajax POST request but I'm having troubles understanding how I can return the updated value. Here's my script

```
    function ajaxTest(){
        var text = "text to send";
        $.ajax({
            url:'test/',
            type:'POST',
            data:{text : text, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            success:function () {
                console.log("Ajax test success")
            },

            error:function () {
                console.log("Ajax test failure")
            }
        })
    }
```

My urlpatterns:

```
from .views import *
urlpatterns=[
    path('test/', testingAjax),
]
```

And I have view that get this text

```
def testingAjax(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        x = request.POST.get('text')
        textToReturn = x + " text to return"
        return HttpResponse #And here trouble begins
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        status = "Nuh uh"
        return HttpResponse(status)
```

What should I put in `HttpResponse` and how can I catch this data in javascript now (for console log it for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply return HttpResponse(textToReturn).

However, you will likely want to look into [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) and return a data structure for your javascript to do something with.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse

def testingAjax(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    x = request.POST.get('text')
    textToReturn = x + " text to return"
    return JsonResponse({'result':textToReturn,})
elif request.method == 'GET':
    status = "Nuh uh"
    return HttpResponse(status)
```

For the javascript to log the data that comes back in your first example would be like:

```
function ajaxTest(){
    var text = "text to send";
    $.ajax({
        url:'test/',
        type:'POST',
        data:{text : text, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        success:function (data) {
            console.log("Ajax test success");
            console.log(data);
        },

        error:function () {
            console.log("Ajax test failure")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But what will happen if request from the view will take some time? Will js function just "wait" for the answer or it will return something like Null?

Comment: Yes. Some other options around timeout and complete are in the jQuery Ajax documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/